# On the left were, on the right (were)

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

> On the left were the sinks, on the right (were) the stalls.

Can (were) be omitted in the second part of the sentence?

I searched this construction on [Google Books](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=cL6DAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA53&dq=%22on%20the%20left%20were%20the%22%20right&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBmpD6pvTmAhUSqpQKHQEiBoo4ChDoAQg_MAM#v=onepage&q=%22on%20the%20left%20were%20the%22%20right&f=false). They do add the second were/was:

> On the left were the bookcases, and on the right was a perpendicular
>   stone wall.

But since my sentence is short, maybe I can omit the second *were*? Or maybe I shouldn't?

Comment: The second instance of ***were*** is a "predictable repetition" within a "parallel syntactic construction", so it can optionally be "deleted". Note that if such a "predictable" element is a ***verb***, native speakers don't care if the *actual* word "deleted" in the second instance is different becauise of singular/plural forms. So *On the left **was** a man, on the right [**were**] two women* and *On the left were two women, on the right [**was**] a man* are both fine, ***with or without the highlighted word that's being "repeated"***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but punctuate it like this:

> On the left were the sinks; on the right, the stalls.

The comma I have inserted is a *[gapping comma](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/comma/gapping)* to show that words have been omitted instead of repeated - in this case, the word "were" has been omitted.

I've also replaced your comma with a semicolon. This is to fix a [comma splice](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma-splice/), also called a *comma fault* - when you join two independent clauses with a comma and no conjunction. Your second example has a conjunction ("and"), so in that example, you could just insert the gapping comma in place of "was".

Some comments have suggested that the semicolon is unnecessary, and in most cases I would agree that it is. As a semicolon is read as a pause in the same way a comma is, most modern English writers just use the comma. However, when the gapping comma is inserted, the two commas could be confusing to a reader as they may not discern as quickly why the second comma is there. Changing it to a semicolon avoids that confusion and makes it obvious that there is a gapping comma. I'm not being dogmatic about this latter point and you can take or leave my advice.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with reducing the semicolon to a comma, and discarding *your* comma completely. In fact, I'm pretty sure that the *average* tendency in modern writing would be moving towards such "lighter" punctuation.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I agree that the semicolon isn't always mandatory, but the gapping comma is definitely needed if words are omitted. The pause would be there if you spoke it. If someone spoke that sentence without a pause there I would be asking them to repeat themselves. When I wrote it with two commas, it just looked messy. I'm sticking with my answer.

Comment: To me also, the semicolon is rare and unnecessary here.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie I agree, semicolons are increasingly rare. I've added some explanation into my answer as to why I am recommending it here. There are other alternatives - the sentence could just use a conjunction instead.

Comment: @Astralbee You suggestion makes sense. But isn't it a bit strange to regard "on the right, the stalls" as an independent clause? (Out of context, there's no way of telling that a "were" was omitted.)

Comment: @alexchenco The two clauses are 1) the stuff on the left, and 2) the stuff on the right. The gapping comma does not make another clause, the two were already there in your original sentence. "On the right the stalls" out of context is ungrammatical, so yes it is clear there is a word missing.

Comment: I *completely* disagree with the "syntactically mandatory" implications of *the gapping comma is definitely needed if words are omitted.* If you want to observe that particular "orthographic rule" in all cases, I have no objection. But it is essentially a stylistic choice. [This guy](https://www.tonythistlewood.com/writing-tips.html) says *A gapping comma may be omitted, if the meaning is clear without it.* But I'd rather "qualify" the "rule of thumb" by saying *if you could reasonably **say** the words without including a noticeable **pause** where a repeated element was "deleted"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica But [this guy](https://thewritepractice.com/how-to-make-your-editor-hate-you-splice-your-commas/) says that editors hate comma splices and they should be avoided, and you're saying they are fine? I've clarified in my answer that I am not being dogmatic, but I've supported my arguments with links so the OP can read and decide whether they want to be "creative" with grammar, or follow established rules. Frankly, I don't know how you can be dogmatic about *ignoring* a rule.

Comment: I'm a *long* way from being dogmatic! My whole point here is that I feel the way you presented things implies that *you're* the dogmatic one! Or perhaps I should say *implied that you were*, since your edits have given some ground on this point. I've no problem with it being pointed out that a "gapping comma" *usually* (or even *nearly always*) replaces the "deleted" repetition, and it might even make sense to advise *learners* that they should/must always do this. But the bottom line is it's not a "universal rule" that all competent writers are "obliged" to follow in all contexts.

Comment: As an example where I think it would be "stylistically weak" to include the gapping comma, [*A medal was struck upon this occasion with the faces of the King and Queen on one side, and **on the other a ship** at anchor, with boats fishing on the wreck: ...*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=lxhoBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA143&dq=%22on+one+side%22+%22on+the+other+a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmq9XSwvTmAhVqMewKHS-IDMUQ6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=%22on%20one%20side%22%20%22on%20the%20other%20a%22&f=false) (the sentence continues; my point is few people would pause at the deleted second instance of ***side*** there)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Your initial argument was that modern, progressive English isn't written that way, but your supporting text is a racist book from 1827 that refers to "black slaves.... illiterate and unpolished"?

Comment: Wot?! So "racists" can't speak English now? Seriously, there are plenty of more recent written instances of [**on one side and on the other**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22on+one+side+and+on+the+other%22) that aren't followed by a comma. I just didn't think I was expected to be that PC in my choice of example.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica That's kind of a strawman argument. You've completely avoided the fact the book was published in 1872. Maybe racists can speak English, but 1872 racists can't speak *modern* English, and they aren't particularly known for being progressive. My case rests.